# ProgressManager. Cancel button

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In my plugin, I execute a network query, get the result
and show the processing step.

[image]

```
CoreProgressManager.getInstance().runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(Runnable {
        //runnable block
        CoreProgressManager.getInstance().progressIndicator.text  = "Start loading"
        val result = MyProvider.getObjects() // this network request
        CoreProgressManager.getInstance().progressIndicator.text  = "Finish"
        result.forEach {
            //processing result
            CoreProgressManager.getInstance().progressIndicator.text  = "Processing is $result"
        }
    }, taskTitle, true /* canBeCanceled */, project)
```

Sometimes the query is performed by the network for a long time, and I want to stop working all block (runnable block).
For this, in `runProcessWithProgressSynchronously` I passed the parameter `canBeCanceled = true`
and naively thought that IDEA would stop executing my executable block, but this did not happen.

How do I catch the clicking of a Cancel button and stop my runnable block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to periodically call `ProgressIndicator.checkCanceled()` from your block. This method will throw a `ProcessCanceledException` if the Cancel button has been pressed.